# Heading to an URL after a reboot

Tags: php, redirect

I built a user-interface to change the IP Adress from my raspberry pi.
Now I want the browser heading to my new IP Adress, after a reboot automatically...
Something like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['reboot'] ) ) {
  exec("/sbin/shutdown -r now");
  header("Location: $new_ip");
}
```

It's clear to me, that this can't work, because if I execute the reboot nothing else will processed.

I saw this function in many user-interfaces like from Synology.

Comment: Unless that browser is started at boot AND set up to go to the last page loaded I can't see how this could ever work as described. Run a `bat` file at startup that calls the browser the with current IP perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, but I think there must be an easier way to solve this.
I mean how does Synology and all the other manufacturer do this.
Maybe with an other programming language?

Comment: They put an entry in the `RunOnce` registry entry to make an update or whatever and remove that entry after it has been run once.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit your hosts file and set a reference from you new IP to some address.
For example 10.0.0.138 my.random.ip.com (Where 10.0.0.138 is your new IP).
Now in your browser you can set that IP for new opened tab (In chrome go to advance settings and look for 'on startup').